# Value is not fetching on select PHP

Tags: php

I am fetching selected value on select, values are stored in session. I am now fetching by echoing variable name `$gender` but it's not displaying selected value which I selected earlier.

My code

```
<select value="<?php echo $gender; ?>">
    <option>Male</option>
    <option>Female</option>
</select>
```

Can you guyz tell me, what's wrong I am doing here

Comment: should be like this : <option value="male" >Male</option>

Comment: @pradeep Then if I select female what will be the output then? male or female?

Comment: value should be set in option , you should add also do <option value="female" >Female</option>

Comment: Option has a value `property`. and you are showing value in select . So it should be like `<option value="<?php echo $gender; ?>">Male</option>`

Comment: @pradeep Okay then where do I need to put this `value="<?php echo $gender; ?>"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<select>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) doesn't work like that. It uses the `selected` attribute in the `<option>`:

```
<select name="gender">
    <option value="male" <?php echo $gender=="male"?"selected":""; ?>>Male</option>
    <option value="female" <?php echo $gender=="female"?"selected":""; ?>>Female</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Did you also add the `value="male"` ? The comparison is case sensitive and be default the value is what's inside the `<option>` tags.